# MatrixPlot ignores ColorFunction for 0 matrices

Tags: plotting, color

I noticed that when plotting a matrix with custom color function there seems to be a special behavior for matrices with just 0's. 
In this case the plot is simply white. If there is one non-zero everything works correctly. Any ideas?

```
MatrixPlot[{{0, 0.5}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image: correct output]

but

```
MatrixPlot[{{0, 0}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image: unexpected output]

where we would expect a black cells.
(Mathematica 10.0.2 Linux)

Comment: `ArrayPlot[]` exhibits the same problem, apparently.

Comment: Should I file a bug report? What do you think.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I see the same behavior on MMA 10.4: something funny is going on here. This is really an extended comment rather than an answer.

You could define your own graylevel function that also prints the values passed to it for evaluation, to check what is going on:

```
Clear[gray]
gray[x_] := Module[{}, Print[x]; RGBColor[x, x, x]]
```

and use in MatrixPlot:

```
MatrixPlot[{{0, 0.5}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> gray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see the correct values seem to be passed to our color function, and interpreted correctly.

Normally MatrixPlot would send each value to be converted into color to the colorfunction separately:

```
MatrixPlot[{{0.2, 0.2}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> gray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when those values are all zeros, then only one single value is sent to the colorfunction:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the incorrectly colored plot is returned.

Even in cases in which the correct plot is returned, the zero values are conflated into one call to the colorfunction:

```
MatrixPlot[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.5}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> gray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Perhaps `MatrixPlot` is being too clever here and applying some kind of internal optimization?

Comment: Also, look at this weirdness:  `ListDensityPlot[ConstantArray[0, {#, #}], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel] & /@ {2,
   3, 4, 5}`

Comment: @JasonB easy. The list plots accept data in two forms: array and point-value form. For `ListDensityPlot`, the point-value form is `{{x, y, z} ..}` which is exactly what you're sending it with `ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}]`. And, you're sending it 3 points at the same location, so it really can't do anything sensible.

Comment: @rcollyer You mean it can't tell the difference between a $3\times3$ array and a list of 3 $\{x, y, z\}$ values? Unbelievable  :-D (also, I feel dumb on that one lol)

Comment: @JasonB I know, shocking! (well at least about it's limitations). Don't feel dumb, this hits many people. It's even more confusing when your working with a $n\times 3$ pencil ...

Comment: @JasonB I don't, [Ilian](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) might.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the comment. I had the printing myself to see whether my function was somehow wrong in the first place. Anyway, the function is only called ones and returns the right value. Still the plot is wrong.