# ArrayPlot with a user-defined color function is misbehaving

Tags: plotting, bugs, color

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.0**

---

I am using `ArrayPlot` to show some arrays with values from 0 to 1. I want 0 to be black and 1 to be white, so I am using:

```
ColorFunction -> Function[a, RGBColor[a, a, a]]
```

(I realize I could use `GrayLevel`, but I eventually want to play with the components of `RGBcolor`).

The problem is that, in the context of `ArrayPlot`, this color function seems to misbehave with zero arrays. It plots the array with cells that are empty (opacity 0) instead of black. Even one value in the array greater than zero, however small, and all the cells plot fine.

Note that I am using `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

I finally discovered a work-around by using the explicit alpha channel of `RGBColor`, but I think that should not be necessary.

#### Code example

```
{ArrayPlot[{{0}}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[a, RGBColor[a, a, a]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
 ArrayPlot[{{0}}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[a, RGBColor[a, a, a, 1]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]}
```

The first produces an empty square (transparent), the second a black one. Both should be black, no?

#### Other information

- The same happens with `MatrixPlot`.
- No problem with other plot functions, like `DensityPlot`, or `ListDensityPlot` (even with `InterpolationOrder -> 0`)
- I'm using *Mathematica* 10.4.0.0

Comment: This does look like some kind of bug, e.g. if your color function is `Function[a,RGBColor[1,a,a]]` it returns a red square. It seems to just not like a black square. If you look at the `FullForm` it uses a `SparseArray` with no elements to represent your data, even though you didn't ask it to, but only in the case when all the data is BLACK with no alpha channel. `ColorRules->{0->Black,1->White}` produces the same result. Another workaround is to do `RGBColor[a+$MachineEpsilon,a,a]`.

Comment: I'm using 10.0.1.0 on OSX.

Comment: I believe this is the intended function of ArrayPlot. From the Details and Options section of the [`ArrayPlot` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html#):
_"If array contains 0s and 1s, the 1s will appear as black squares and the 0s as white squares."_

Comment: Since `ArrayPlot` returns `Graphics[Raster[data],opts]`, it might be easier to work directly with `Raster`,which supports RGB entries.

Comment: @Rashid That statement is about the default behavior; it doesn't apply if you're specifying `ColorRules` or `ColorFunction`.

Comment: Can somebody track how far back this goes before adding [tag:bugs]? Thanks.

Comment: @J.M. It works properly using version 9.0.1. My answer is based on version 10.4.1, Windows 10 x64.

Comment: To check if your *Mathematica* version is effected by this bug, evaluate `InputForm@Reverse[SparseArray[{{0.}}]]`. If the output is `SparseArray[Automatic, {1, 1}, 0., {1, {{0, 0}, {}}, Pattern}]`, it's buggy. If the output is `SparseArray[Automatic, {1, 1}, 0., {1, {{0, 0}, {}}, {}}]`, it's fine. Please update the bug header accordingly.

Comment: @Karsten, no problem; all I was asking was that the header info be made as accurate as possible since that's the point of the entire [tag:bugs] business anyway. :)

Answer (score 8):

### Workarounds until this bug has been fixed:

**1) `ArrayPlot` workaround**

Using

```
arrayPlot[data_List] := Block[{list = Reverse@data, Reverse},
  Reverse[x_] := x;
  ArrayPlot[list, ColorFunction -> Function[a, RGBColor[a, a, a]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
  ]
```

instead of `ArrayPlot`.

**2) Fixing `Reverse`**

```
Unprotect@Reverse;
Reverse[x_SparseArray] := SparseArray[Reverse[Normal@x]]
Protect@Reverse;
```

---

### Tracking down the problem

I think this is a bug due to the creation of an improper `SparseArray` for the `Raster` of the `ArrayPlot`.

```
ap = ArrayPlot[{{0}}, ColorFunction -> Function[a, RGBColor[a, a, a]], 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False];

{sa} = Cases[ap, _SparseArray, Infinity]
```

[image: sa]

The normal expression

```
Normal[sa]
```

> `{{0.}}`

looks OK, but

```
InputForm[sa]
```

> `SparseArray[Automatic, {1, 1}, 0., {1, {{0, 0}, {}}, Pattern}]`

looks suspicious to me, because of `Pattern` at the end.

If this `SparseArray` is replaced with its `Normal` form, the expected output is produced.

```
ap /. _SparseArray -> Normal[sa]
```

A replacement with `SparseArray[{{0.}}]` also results in the correct output.

```
ap /. _SparseArray -> SparseArray[{{0.}}]
```

---

```
SparseArray[{{0.}}]
```

[image: newSA]

```
% // InputForm
```

> `SparseArray[Automatic, {1, 1}, 0., {1, {{0, 0}, {}}, {}}]`

---

The flawed `SparseArray` is created by the evaluation of

```
SparseArray[{{0.}}] // Reverse
```

inside of

```
Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`ArrayPlotInternal[False, {{0}}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[a, RGBColor[a, a, a]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

which is called by `ArrayPlot[{{0}}, ColorFunction -> Function[a, RGBColor[a, a, a]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`.

---

`SparsArray`s with all elements being `0` having other dimensions are effected by the same bug:

```
SparseArray[{{0., 0, 0}}] // Reverse // InputForm
```

> `SparseArray[Automatic, {1, 3}, 0, {1, {{0, 0}, {}}, Pattern}]`

```
SparseArray[{{0., 0}, {0., 0}}] // Reverse // InputForm
```

> `SparseArray[Automatic, {2, 2}, 0, {1, {{0, 0, 0}, {}}, Pattern}]`

---

The reason why using `ColorFunction -> Function[a, RGBColor[a, a, a, 1]]` is not effected by this bug is that

```
Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`ConvertToColorTensor[{{0.}}, -∞, ∞, 
 Function[a, RGBColor[a, a, a, 1]], "Automatic", False, None, Automatic, False]
```

evaluates to the `List`

> `{{{0., 0., 0., 1.}}}`

while

```
Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`ConvertToColorTensor[{{0.}}, -∞, ∞, 
 Function[a, RGBColor[a, a, a]], "Automatic", False, None, Automatic, False]
```

returns a `SparseArray`

[image: SparseArray_PNG]

Comment: This problem had cropped up [not long ago](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112508/27951) in the context of `MatrixPlot`; `ArrayPlot` had also been mentioned as having the same problem. At that time we were convinced it was a likely bug, but couldn't find its origin. I think your analysis goes quite a bit further than I could at that time. Thanks!